# how to test my custom exception with unit test

Tags: java, spring, junit, java-8, mocking

Hello I have wrote a test cases for my logic and all these are working nicely. however, I have no idea how to test my custom exceptions. My code below;

```
 @Component
    public class PlaneFactory {
    
        public Plane getPlane(String planeType) {
        
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(planeType)) {
                throw new PlaneTypeNotFoundException();
            }
        
            if (planeType.equalsIgnoreCase("lightJet")) {
                return new LightJet();
        
            } else if (planeType.equalsIgnoreCase("midJet")) {
                return new MidJet();
            }
           
            else {
                 throw new InvalidPlaneTypeException();
                 }

       my custom exceptions below;


     PlaneTypeNotFoundException class below;


public class PlaneTypeNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 4314211343358454345L;
    
        public PlaneTypeNotFoundException() {
    
            super("You have not enter anything to check a plane");
        }
    
    }
    InvalidPlaneTypeException below;



public class InvalidPlaneTypeException extends RuntimeException {
          
        public InvalidPlaneTypeException() {
    
            super("You need to enter one of following plane types : {LightJet, MidJet}");
        }
    
    }
```

which methods are suitable to use ? I mean in this scenario should I use assertThrows or just use expected annotations ?

for PlaneTypeNotFoundException I have tried something below which it did not work

```
@Test
public void testPlaneFactory_isEmptyOrNull_ThenReturnException() {

    String planeType = "";

    LightJet lightJet= (LightJet) planeFactory.getPlane(planeType);

    assertThrows(PlaneNotFoundException.class, () -> lightJet.getType().equalsIgnoreCase(planeType), "You have not enter anything to check a plane");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I follow your code correctly then the executable lambda in `assertThrows()` should be the code that you expect to generate the exception:

```
public void testPlaneFactory_isEmptyOrNull_ThenReturnException() {
    assertThrows(PlaneNotFoundException.class, () -> planeFactory.getPlane(""));
}
```

If it *does* throw an exception then the test should pass.

A test for the second case would be:

```
void testInvalidPlaneType() {
    assertThrows(InvalidPlaneTypeException.class, () -> planeFactory.getPlane("doh"));
}
```

Comment: No worries, JUnit has always been a bit funky when it comes to testing for exceptions.